# Slow querying speed for RODBC with Vertica

Tags: odbc, vertica, rodbc

I usually access Vertica in two ways: `vsql` in command line and `RODBC` through `R`. However, queries taking ~ 20s in `vsql` will usually 10-15 minutes through RODBC. Does anyone have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the vertica.log, you might be able to see when your sql statement is actually getting processed, or if it's actually held up by queuing or something else.

Calling with the same user?

Comment: I don't think it is a queuing issue. I tried to query using `vsql` right after using `RODBC`, (and the other way round) the time taken is always very different. I am wondering if `vsql` doesn't require any formatting and `RODBC` tries to parse the data into `data.frame`. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Very probably this is a Fetch issue. I'd suggest:

**Option 1:** continue using RODBC and increase the number of rows retrieved per Fetch cycle (rows_at_time). For example:

```
ch <- odbcConnect("mydsn", uid="mouser", pwd=“XXX", rows_at_time=8192)
```

**Option 2:** try replacing RODBC with RJDBC.